# Horizontal scrolling + scrollbar

Tags: css, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

I want to build a page, where a certain `DIV` element in the middle of the page is horizontally scrollable (big width + `overflow-x: scroll`). The scrollbar will show up at the bottom of this `DIV`.

Is it possible to show a scrollbar at the very bottom of the page (so not at the bottom of the div) which only scrolls the content in that scrollable `DIV` in the middle of the page?

I ask this question, because I want to place content underneath the scrollable `DIV`, and I want the user to be able to scroll the horizontal `DIV` with a scrollbar that is places underneath this content.

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="slider">
        # Slider content here
    </div>

    <ul class="job_listings scrollable">
        <li>job 1</li>
        <li>job 2</li>
        <li>job 3</li>
        <li>job 4</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="about us">
        # About us content here
    </div>

    ** here I want the scrollbar of the ul job_listings to appear, at the very bottom of the page **

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please share html as well what you are trying?

Comment: I added my html code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to achieve this by adding `position: fixed;` to the non-scrollable content.

```
.slider {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; // Assuming you want this to be on top
}
.about_us {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; // Assuming you want this to be on the bottom
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2c6t567/1/)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the only possible solution to lay out the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-bottom:180px` like i did here http://jsfiddle.net/v6ohjw32/ 
and remove `border:2px solid green;` to eliminate borders

Comment: I believe he wants the scrollbar to be at the very bottom of the page and full-width, just like a native browser scrollbar.

Comment: That is true, it needs to be at the very bottom

Comment: you may increase the padding-bottom magnitude according to your need

Comment: This will just push down the content underneath it.